# CSS, Stylus: conditional "else" is ignored

Tags: css, conditional-statements, stylus

I'm trying to create Mixins in Stylus that would allow me to define in one line two different colors of an element for `.theme-bright` and `.theme-dark`. Base on [this](https://stylus-lang.com/docs/conditionals.html), here's my current simplified code:

```
insert-Variable(Name, Value-bright, Value-dark)
  if theme-is-bright
    --color-{Name}: Value-bright
  else if theme-is-dark
    --color-{Name}: Value-dark

Variables()
  insert-Variable(Element1, black, white)
  insert-Variable(Element2, black, white)
  insert-Variable(Element3, black, white)

.theme-bright
  theme-is-dark = false
  theme-is-bright = true
  Variables()

.theme-dark
  theme-is-bright = false
  theme-is-dark = true
  Variables()
```

I would expect it to yield this:

```
.theme-bright
  --color-Element1: black;
  --color-Element2: black;
  --color-Element3: black;
.theme-dark
  --color-Element1: white;
  --color-Element2: white;
  --color-Element3: white;
```

Instead, I'm getting this:

```
.theme-bright
  --color-Element1: black;
  --color-Element2: black;
  --color-Element3: black;
.theme-dark
  --color-Element1: black;
  --color-Element2: black;
  --color-Element3: black;
```

Switching `--color-{Name}: Value-bright` with `--color-{Name}: Value-dark` also switches this unintended result: the values under both `.theme-bright` and `.theme-dark` now become `white`. So, apparently, whatever value defined under `else if` is ignored or overridden by the one under `if`.

Changing `else if ...` to just `else` doesn't fix this: it still picks up only the value defined under `if`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to update global variables, but it doesn't work in the context of a selector, so just move them out of the selector:

```
theme-is-dark = false
theme-is-bright = true

.theme-bright
  Variables()

theme-is-bright = false
theme-is-dark = true

.theme-dark
  Variables()
```

However, from this code snippet, it appears you're making it harder than it needs to be by using 2 different variables to convey the same information: `theme-is-bright = true` ought to be equivalent to `theme-is-dark = false`, but neither of the statements in the `insert-Variable` mixin would know what to do with `theme-is-dark = false`. You further need a *pair* of values to convey a single point of information, and the other permutations may create unexpected results. I'd definitely recommend whittling this down to a single variable.

Finally, for the sake of clarity, I would also recommend adding the value to [the mixin as an argument](https://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=%2F%2F%20mixins%0Ainsert-Variable(is-bright%2C%20Name%2C%20Value-bright%2C%20Value-dark)%0A%20%20if%20is-bright%0A%20%20%20%20--color-%7BName%7D%3A%20Value-bright%0A%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20--color-%7BName%7D%3A%20Value-dark%0A%0Atheme-is-bright%20%3D%20true%0A%0A.theme-bright%0A%20%20insert-Variable(theme-is-bright%2C%20Element1%2C%20black%2C%20white)%0A%20%20insert-Variable(theme-is-bright%2C%20Element2%2C%20black%2C%20white)%0A%20%20insert-Variable(theme-is-bright%2C%20Element3%2C%20black%2C%20white)%0A%0Atheme-is-bright%20%3D%20false%0A%0A.theme-dark%0A%20%20insert-Variable(theme-is-bright%2C%20Element1%2C%20black%2C%20white)%0A%20%20insert-Variable(theme-is-bright%2C%20Element2%2C%20black%2C%20white)%0A%20%20insert-Variable(theme-is-bright%2C%20Element3%2C%20black%2C%20white)). This is a coding style recommendation, as it does not effectively change what you have to do, but will be likely end up a bit more readable.